# Filtering IQueryable result set using parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm getting confused with this and I know there will be a more slick way of starting it off. The 'result' variable has many records and I want to check if IN_SiteId is > 0 and filter on it, same after that for LandownerId and PaymentCategoryId etc. If I can get the right approach for the first 2 I will be ok from there. This should be easier but having a brick wall day. Any comments appreciated

```
public IQueryable rptRentPaidMonthly(int IN_SiteId, int IN_LandownerId, int IN_PaymentCategoryId, int IN_PaymentTypeId, string IN_ShowRelevantProportion)
{

    var result = this._lmsDb.rptRentPaidMonthly(IN_daysFrom, IN_daysTo, IN_SiteId, IN_LandownerId, IN_PaymentCategoryId, IN_PaymentTypeId, IN_ShowRelevantProportion);

    if (IN_SiteId > 0)
    {
        var searchResults = (from s in result
                             where (s.SiteId == @IN_SiteId)
                             select s);

        return searchResults.AsQueryable();
    }

    return result.AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a LINQ expert but I think you can do something like this:

```
public IQueryable rptRentPaidMonthly(int IN_SiteId, int IN_LandownerId, int IN_PaymentCategoryId, int IN_PaymentTypeId, string IN_ShowRelevantProportion)
{
    var result = this._lmsDb.rptRentPaidMonthly(IN_daysFrom, IN_daysTo, IN_SiteId, IN_LandownerId, IN_PaymentCategoryId, IN_PaymentTypeId, IN_ShowRelevantProportion);


    var searchResults = (from s in result
                         where (IN_SiteId <= 0 || s.SiteId == IN_SiteId)
                                && (IN_LandownerId <= 0 || s.LandownerId == IN_LandownerId)
                                && (IN_PaymentCategoryId <= 0 || s.PaymentCategoryId == IN_PaymentCategoryId)
                                && (IN_PaymentTypeId <= 0 || s.PaymentTypeId == In_PaymentTypeId)
                         select s);

    return searchResults.AsQueryable();
}
```

The `where` clause checks if each filter value is less than or equal to 0, if so then it will return true and will not evaluate the next bit which attempts to filter the actual field on the value provided.